# add markups/comments in BIM 360's PDF

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

just wonder if there's 3rd party app for pdf editor in BIM 360? or prototype/sample of Forge / BIM 360 API?
at minimum, can add markups/comments if not fully editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in BIM 360, I think there is an integrated Markups tool that you can do simple edit, just open the PDF file, turn on Markups tool, and you can see the simple toolbar to do basic edit, attached the picture just for your reference.

[image]

If you want to do it in your own App by yourself, you can use Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore extension to implement, please check the blog at https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/implementing-custom-markups

Comment: thanks Zhong, have a great weekend and talk to you soon.

Comment: Nice talked to you Joe, if the answer helps, please mark it as solution, this will benefit more people with same question:)